# Where do I ask "What are video games nowadays considered as"?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, stack-exchange

I have the following question which I'm unsure on which site in the SE network it would be on-topic:

> Nowadays, the majority of people consider video games as a form of light entertainment. But  to me, it seems that they have become a large part of our lives. Many games are competitive in spirit and some even allow you to experience things that you have never done in real life.
>
> I've never piloted a plane before (*maybe one day in the future I will learn  but until that day arrives, I haven't*) but there is a game called *Battlefield 3* on mission part 4, which lets me experience what it must be like to pilot a plane.
>
> *If you don't know what is the campaign of the game, I'll leave the source at [HERE](https://www.ign.com/wikis/battlefield-3/Going_Hunting).
>
> So I'm curious nowadays video games have already taken over a  significant part of our lives.

Which site would accept my question?

Comment: You want to know where to ask this question?

Comment: I already put a tag about site-recommendation... Why there are a lot down vote =.=

Comment: Because it was unclear what you asked for. The [tag info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/site-recommendation/info) has guidance on how these kind of questions are best asked. Just tagging it and hope for the best isn't always a successful approach.

Comment: Thanks for edit the post. Appreciate!

Comment: May I know what is the reason why there are still have down vote? I thought the question would be edit good enough already...

Comment: @kit people need to actively revisit and reverse their votes, they don't magically disappear after an edit ;). Looks to me you didn't get any new downvotes for a while now, the post should be okay.

Comment: FYI: "*there is a game called Battlefield 3 on mission part 4, which lets me experience what it must be like to pilot a plane.*" Flight simulators on home-available machines predate BF3 by *decades*.

Comment: Your post still doesn't have a question I can identify as being acceptable anywhere. You can consider a computer game as anything you like, and there is such a wide variety of games, there will be a plethora of descriptions. And as a pilot, I'd agree with Nicol - flight Sims can be realistic, Battlefield 3 isn't...

Comment: I see you posted the [question](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/23344/what-are-video-games-nowadays-considered-as) but the grammar and vocabulary mistakes make it difficult to understand. For one thing, we do not "ride" aeroplanes, we can either "fly on a plane", as passengers, or we "pilot" them if we are taking the plane in flight.

Comment: And I didn't change “If you don't know what is the campaign of the game, I'll leave the source…” because I didn't understand what you meant by *campaign*? Did you means "scope", "aim", "purpose", "object"??

Comment: I apologise for my huge grammar mistake.... I leave the source for you to see what is campaign mean to me. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Campaign_(role-playing_games)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd guess the *topic* "how video games affect our lives" is psychology, which is handled on [Psychology Stack Exchange](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/). An example question: [Does playing video games increase attention and learning agility, therefore career performance](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/12497/14337)

That said, I understand your example but what you're actually asking is still unclear to me. Perhaps you can work with one of the regulars to better formulate your question? Their [main chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2250/the-axon-terminal) is rather quiet, but it's probably worth a try.